# SQLLDR: dynamic load of lobfile concatenating full path and filename

Tags: path, concatenation, sql-loader

I'm using sQLLDER (11g) to load data into a table. One of the columns is a BLOB, that needs to be loaded from another file. The name of the file depends on a field of the table, and I need to concatenate the full path in order to be able to load the file. So in order to have the full path of the file,  I need to concatenate the folder path '/oradata/val/' with the field ID_RECOMMENDATION plus the extension '.dat'; for example, if the field ID_RECOMMENDATION is '1', the filename should be '/oradata/val/1.dat'. I can not modify the original file, so I want to use an expression to get the full path for the file, using something like this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE t_val_recommendation append
fields terminated by ';'
(
  ID_RECOMMENDATION,
  ID_PROFILE       ,
  START_DATE       date 'yyyymmdd',
  LOBF_00001       BOUNDFILLER"trim('/oradata/val/'||:ID_RECOMMENDATION||'.dat')",
  PARAGRAPHS       LOBFILE (LOBF_00001) TERMINATED BY EOF,
  ASSET_ALLOCATION
)
```

But it doesn't seem to understand the concatenation of the path and filename. How can I do that?

thanks

(Edited to clarify meaning)

This is the table schema:

```
  ID_RECOMMENDATION  NUMBER(10)                 NOT NULL,             
  ID_PROFILE         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)          NOT NULL,
  START_DATE         DATE                       NOT NULL,
  PARAGRAPHS         SYS.XMLTYPE,
  ASSET_ALLOCATION   SYS.XMLTYPE
```

And this would be a line to be loaded:

```
1;CONSERVATIVE;20120301;<aa>This is my asset allocation</aa>
```

Comment: it looks like you're trying to skip the loading of column "LOBF_00001" but you want to use it later, right?

Comment: not exactly. I want to load an xml file which is in the folder /oradata/val, and the name is the field IF_RECOMMENDATION of the record. I want to be able to concatenate both the path and the file name, and load it into the field PARAGRAPHS

Comment: Could you please add table schema PLUS one sample line of the CTL after the BEGINDATA line, so that we know what field of data maps to what column in the database

Comment: Are external tables a possibility?  I'll stop suggesting alternative approaches if indeed you absolutely have to use SQLLDR but it just seems to me that it would be simpler and easier to use a different approach than the one you're taking right now.  Ultimately just trying to suggest ways that will help you out in the end...

Comment: I just added the table schema and a sample line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how hard it would be for you to modify the existing file(s) that are being loaded in, but is it possible to modify those files to already contain the correct file path?  You could possibly use Java or some other text processing language to concatenate that ID_RECOMMENDATION with '/oradata/val/' & '.dat' and save the file(s) and then it would be a simple change to load in your file(s) using...

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE t_val_recommendation append
fields terminated by ';'
(
  ID_RECOMMENDATION,
  ID_PROFILE       ,
  START_DATE       date 'yyyymmdd',
  LOBF_00001       FILLER char,
  PARAGRAPHS       LOBFILE (LOBF_00001) TERMINATED BY EOF
)
```

There's many languages available that are easy to learn and do text file transformations.  Java, Perl & C# are three that come right to mind but there are many others available.

I would say setting up your text files in a format that will be easy to use by SQLLDR will be well worth the effort in the long run.

Comment: I know that. I was hoping for some other way to do that, since the same file needs to be loaded on other servers, in which the path will change. I just don't understander why it is possible to do operations like that on any normal field, but not in a FILLER field. It's kind of absurd.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOBF_00001       BOUNDFILLER"trim('/oradata/val/'||:ID_RECOMMENDATION||'.dat')"
```

this seems a mistake to me:

- if this is a `BOUNDFILLER`, it means that there is **NO** column named `LOBF_00001` in your table `t_val_recommendation`, but that there is data in your data section of the ctl file, that you want to consume it and store it into the `LOBF_00001` variable, that can be used to compute other expressions.
- if this is an `EXPRESSION`, it means that there **is** a column named `LOBF_00001` in your table `t_val_recommendation`, but that there is **NO** data in the data section of the ctl file.